# Make shared component with calling navigation.navigate() inside - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-0.46

I want to make shared component for all screen in react native. So I can share them between main components.

[image]

See my code below, everything works but the `this.props.navigation.navigation.navigate('HireJob')` not working.

**MyCode :**

```js
export default class MyComponent extends Component {

    callAndPush = () =>{
      console.log('callAndPush');
      this.props.navigation.navigate('HireJob')
    }

    render() {
         return (
              <TouchableHighlight style = {{backgroundColor : 'red' , height : 30}} onPress = {() => this.callAndPush()}>
                <Text>Apple</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
         );
    }
}
```

**Use of Component :**

```js
 render(){
    return (
      <View style = {styles.scrollSty}>
            <MyComponent></MyComponent>
     </View>
    );
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @Eden Want to Add one Common in all View. So that I will create one parents class for view.

Comment: `Like <Text></Text> component`?

Comment: I will update the question.

Comment: @Eden I will update with image. can you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it works like this, bypassing `navigation prop` into `MyComponent`.

```js
<MyComponent {...this.props} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Every component can be imported into other components, such as navigators. They import your scenes and navigate between them by sharing props.

To make a component and use it in different places simply create one:

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
         return (
              <Text> This is a special component </Text>
         );
    }
}
```

And in your other classes use it like this:

```
import MyComponent from '../path/to/MyComponent';

class AnotherComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
         return (
              <MyComponent />
         );
    }
}
```

Starting from React 0.14, you can create these easier using [stateless components](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#stateless-functional-components):

```
// A functional component using an ES2015 (ES6) arrow function:
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  return <Text> This is a special component </Text>
};
```

You can pass data using props if you like.

Comment: Yes, I will added TouchableHighlight in MyComponent. and want to push another controller it give error. undefine is not an object. this2.props.navihation.navigate

Comment: Pass the function as a prop. I will update my answer tonighy

Comment: Now updated code. in MyComponent have one function callAndPush and working fine but issue to push with stack navigation.

Comment: This is a different question. I have already explained for the first version. Mark it if this solved your problem at the first place